# Format Array inside array to later use as an E-Mail body

Tags: powershell

I create an empty `$array` early in my script and later i loop over some stuff and want to add this stuff to my array. This works as intended.

```
$AspxFiles = gci $path $filter -r | ? { $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*Werkstatt*' -and `
                                        $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*- Kopie*'   -and `
                                        $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*.1*'        -and `
                                        $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*.0*'        -and `
                                        $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*.2*'        -and `
                                        $_.Name -notlike '*- Kopie*'
                                        }
$array = @()
foreach ($file in $AspxFiles)
{
    $getURL = sls -Path $file.FullName -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | ? { $_ -notlike '*www.w3.org*' -and `
                                                                         $_ -notlike '*jquery.com*' -and `
                                                                         $_ -notlike '*www.mwe*' } | 
    % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }

    foreach ($URL in $getURL)
    {
        $Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL)
        $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
        $Status = [int]$Response.StatusCode
        if ($Status -ne 200 -or $Response.ResponseUri -like '*PageNotFound*') 
        { 
            $x = [PSCustomObject] @{
                File = $file.Name
                URL  = $URL
            } ; $array += $x
        }
        $Response.Close()
    }
}
```

But the output of `$array` is like this:

```
@{File=B-1.56.aspx; URL=http://sdfsdfsdf/b-1.39.4_fr1_d.pdf}
@{File=B-1.56.aspx; URL=http://sdfsdfsdfssd/b-1.39.4_fr1_d.pdf}
@{File=B-1.58.aspx; URL=https://sdfffssd/b-1.39.6_de_d.pdf}
@{File=B-1.58.aspx; URL=https://fsdfsfb-1.39.6_de_d.pdf}
```

How can I get this formatted like a list so I can grab the `File` and `URL` Property to send it as an E-Mail body like this?:

```
$body = $array | sort File | ConvertTo-Html -Property File,URL -Head "<html><h2>Folgende Links wurden im Katalog nicht gefunden:</h2><br></html>" | Out-String
```

Comment: The iterating part in your code is missing as well as the origin of `$file` and `$URL`. IMO it should suffice to omit the `[string[]]` and assign $array the outcome of a foreach ... with the [pscustomobject]

Comment: @LotPings I don't really know what you mean unfortunately... I left the iteration part on purpose because I think it's not necessary but I updatet the question with the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is still only a part of your script but:

- I'd transform your anded wildcards into a -notmatch RegEx with OR'ed `|` entries
- and set `$array = Foreach($file ...` gathering all ouput

---

```
$REDir = '.*Werkstatt.*|.*- Kopie.*|.*\.[012].*'
$REURL = '.*www\.w3\.org.*|.*jquery\.com.*|.*www.mwe.*'

$AspxFiles = Get-ChildItem $path $filter -r | 
    Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $REDir  -and `
                            $_.Name -notlike  '*- Kopie*'}
$array = @()

$array = foreach ($file in $AspxFiles) {
    $getURL = Select-String -Path $file.FullName -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
        Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $REURL } | 
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | ForEach-Obkect { $_.Value }

    ForEach ($URL in $getURL) {
        $Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL)
        $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
        $Status = [int]$Response.StatusCode
        if ($Status -ne 200 -or $Response.ResponseUri -like '*PageNotFound*') { 
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                File = $file.Name
                URL  = $URL
            }
        }
        $Response.Close()
    }
}

$body = $array | Sort-Object File | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Property File,URL -Head `
      "<html><h2>Folgende Links wurden im Katalog nicht gefunden:</h2><br></html>" | 
        Out-String
```